# Why DateTime is 1 day behind from .NET serialized JSON and momentjs format?

Tags: .net, datetime, momentjs

Here's the Date I've on Database for a generic record: `1952-05-17 00:00:00.000`. I do some query, and than I return the data serialized as JSON on client, this way:

```
return Json(new { data = dataFiltered, recordsFiltered = dataTotal, recordsTotal = dataTotal });
```

If I debug, the DataTime field is formatted as follow:

[image]

Expanding properties, that's the situation:

[image]

Looks correct. Now on client, I received the DateTime field as: `/Date(-556250400000)/`

If I try now to format it with momentjs `moment(value).format("DD/MM/YYYY")`, I got `16/05/1952`, which is one day behind.

Why? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/Date(-556250400000)/` represents 1952-05-16T22:00:00Z. It looks like however you've configured the JSON conversion is assuming that the value is in local time, and converting it to UTC.

Ideally, I'd suggest:

- Changing your database to use a date type instead of a date/time type
- Changing the .NET code to use `DateOnly` if you're on .NET 6.0 or above
- Changing the JSON handling to serialize it as an ISO-8601 date ("1952-05-17")

Fundamentally at *every layer* it looks like you're treating this as a date and time (leading to ambiguities as to whether it's in UTC or not) when what you're really trying to represent is a date.

If you *must* keep it in the current representation, I'd suggest using UTC everywhere, to avoid any local time zone considerations coming in. That means I'd expect to see the `DateOfBirth` property showing a `Kind` of Utc.

Comment: Where do I can set to use UTC everywhere? Its a configuration of my application? Is basically an old 4.6.1 ASP.NET MVC app.

Comment: @markzzz: That's up to you to find out. We don't have *nearly* enough context to know that. We don't have any information about what database you're using, how you're accessing it, how you're converting data into JSON etc. And I'm not asking for that information - that really is something you should research for yourself. If you have difficulty with one specific aspect, you should ask a new question with all the relevant details. Note that that shouldn't be an end-to-end question - it should *just* be about (say) database access, or *just* about conversion to JSON.

Comment: First try, converting to date type instead of date/time type: the value is still /Date(-556250400000)/. Uhm...

Comment: @markzzz: That's not really an actionable comment (and in particular it's not clear whether you've changed to DateOnly - I suspect you haven't, if you're using .NET 4.6.1). But again, we've really not got enough context to take you step by step through *every* bit of configuration you'd need to change. I've given you two different approaches you can try to follow - it's up to you to follow through with them.

Comment: I meant your first comment, which doesn't impact the code side (i.e. Changing your database to use a date type instead of a date/time type)

Comment: @markzzz: How would you expect that to change the *last* part (the serialization to JSON) if you're still using `DateTime` in the middle? It's not like the JSON conversion code can see the database configuration (as far as we can tell).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252375/discussion-between-markzzz-and-jon-skeet).

Comment: No, I'm not going to get into this in chat. I've explained why you're seeing what you're seeing and suggested two different options - it's up to you to take it from here.

Comment: I've resolved this way, converting the date as "string" instead of datetime, following the needed formatting: DateOfBirth = SqlFunctions.DateName("day", p.DateOfBirth) + "/" + SqlFunctions.DateName("month", p.DateOfBirth) + "/" + SqlFunctions.DateName("year", p.DateOfBirth)

Comment: edit: this seems better approch DateOfBirth = p.DateOfBirth.HasValue ? DbFunctions.Right("00" + p.DateOfBirth.Value.Day, 2) + "/" + DbFunctions.Right("00" + p.DateOfBirth.Value.Month, 2) + "/" + p.DateOfBirth.Value.Year : "-",